# Group all options with small counts under one label in Power BI charts

Tags: powerbi

I'm creating a PowerBI dashboard for a dataset containing a column "OS", with three main options (Windows, Linux, macOS) as well as in the same column things users entered manually after picking a "Other..." option.

By default, if I render that data in a 1D chart (pie or doughnut), it looks like this:

[image: doughnut chart example]

Something similar happens for e.g. bar charts:

[image: bar chart example]

It looks quite clumsy to have all those options with one or maybe two records as individual items.

Is there a way in the charts or query editor to *automatically* lump the smaller ones together? I'd be happy with a "minimum % for a slice" feature, but also alternatively with a "max N groups" feature (with the last group for "the rest").

I'm happy to do so anywhere in the pipeline as long as it's flexible: input data might change, so writing a computed column with a big switch statement or if/else thing won't help.

Can this be done with Power BI? I can't seem to find a good option anywhere.

Comment: [Luis Vidal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5322050) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977591) saying "This has been submitted as a feature request. [...] [https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=a1717c80-2b97-eb11-89ee-281878e6452b](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=a1717c80-2b97-eb11-89ee-281878e6452b)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Click on the dropdown icon for the field you want to group on. For example, if your doughnut chart is set up with:

- Legend set to "OS" column
- Values as "Count (distinct) of Id"

then click on the dropdown next to "OS":

[image: dropdown next to field]

and then choose "New group". In that dialog you have to:

- Pick the main items and "Group" them.
- Optionally, add other items that belong in those groups.
- Click "Include Other Group" bottom right of the window.

like this...

[image: Grouping dialog]

and finish up. Voila, a "Group" field now exists, to be reused across visualizations.

Not optimal, as it's prone to changes in the data (especially for the "main" groups), but reusable across charts so reasonably useful.